# Moset Tree Category Changes

Tags: joomla

I am created a site using Joomla 3.3 and the Moset Tree extension. I need to allow the users to add listings through the frontend of the website, which I can do easily. However, I need them to be able to change  the category only under a specific root.

An example of this would be:
I have two root categories: Houses and Apartments. The Houses Directory has Single Family Home and Rancher as sub categories. Apartments has One Room and Two Rooms as sub categories. When the user is adding a listing for a House I need them to be able to only select either Houses or one of the two sub directories underneath that. Currently the users have access to add listings into whatever category they wish.

I have tried turning off the Allow Listing submissions for the Apartments category but this method doesn't prevent them from selecting it when they change the category.

I found articles that stated Moset Tree doesn't have the option to lock down categories or listing access by user, so that isn't an option.

I also cannot use Moset Trees Allow changing of category in Add Listing since they need the option to adjust the category.

Answer (score 0):

You can add menu item Add , select Add listing and choose category you want and then when someone want to add listing, he can choose just that category.